# How to update a model from table database first

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I'm create a `context` from database with command like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myConnection;Database=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir MyContext -f
```

After that, I update structure of single table name `MyTable1`.
So, I try to re-run the command with `-Tables` option like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myConnection;Database=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir MyContext -Tables MyTable1 -f
```

I want to update only `MyTable1` and keep stable other table.

But, after run that command, all of table in `Context` file being removed, and it only remains `MyTable1` on `OnModelCreating`.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you use partial classes and avoid modifying the generated code, you can just overwrite all the file when running the second time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and have read about EF Core, database first approach is only supported to generate a `context` once. After creating a `context` from an existing database you have to use migrations for database modifications. `Scaffold-DbContext` will re-created the whole `context` on every execution. ([Here is the source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding#updating-the-model))
Of Course you could re-create after every database modificytion a new `context` - like mentioned in the linked article, but I would suggest to use the code first approach. You could better track all your database changes and it supports you and your colleaugs to work on one project at the same time.

Here is a [link with further information about `-Table` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding). It is used to define which tables are included in `context` at generation process.

> All tables in the database schema are reverse engineered into entity types by 
>   default. You can limit which tables are reverse engineered by
>   specifying schemas and tables.
>
> The `-Schemas` parameter in PMC and the `--schema` option in the CLI can
>   be used to include every table within a schema.
>
> `-Tables` (PMC) and `--table` (CLI) can be used to include specific tables.